# What is the suitable number of queue workers?

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

I was wondering if there is a relation between number of queue workers and CPU or RAM resources. I noticed that Laravel defaults to 8-10 workers, however on my own experience I've tried once to increase them to 50 workers and what a huge and fast performance I get with my Digitalocean VPS 8GB RAM and 4CPUs compared to only 10 workers.

So is there any relation between there number and resources ?

Comment: It all depends on your hardware, what exactly the job is doing and what other services are running on the server. It's very hard to give a good answer on this question, you will have to try some values and find out what works best.

Comment: I can tell that increasing to about 50 workers was making processing faster 5x at least, But why this is not documented in Laravel docs?

Comment: What documentation would be needed?  Of course adding more workers will complete them faster if there is demand, I think that's just common sense.